# How you make procedure in C?

Tags: c

So I'm new to C, I'm trying to make procedure to swap value of 2 variables.
When I run this the swap didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int A,int B)
{
    A = A + B;
    B = A - B;
    A = A - B;
}

int main(void){
    int num1,num2;
    printf("insert first number :\n");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("insert second number :\n");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    swap(num1,num2);

    printf("%d %d\n",num1,num2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the next chapter is the stuff about pointers. Why not read that bit of the book?

Comment: When you pass arguments to a function by value, you shouldn't expect them to be updated in the caller function.

Follow some [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson1.html) please.

Comment: yes, im already done that but the procedures examples i searched not using any pointers in it

Comment: 'When I run this the swap didnt work' - that is incorrect, your function swaps what you coded it to do, (see answers about local vars and pointers).  Also XOR swaps are just inflexible rubbish - use a temp var.

Comment: @EdHeal@jada12276 im like searching and changed things for an hour to the point the code was too complicated for something this simple,             this isnt my original code,(yes im using pointer but the wrong way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because arguments are passed by value and modifying them in callee won't affect caller's local variables. Use pointers to modify ones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void swap(int* A,int* B)
{
    *A = *A + *B;
    *B = *A - *B;
    *A = *A - *B;
}

int main(void){
    int num1=0,num2=0; /* initialize for in case scanf() fails */
    printf("insert first number :\n");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("insert second number :\n");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    swap(&num1,&num2);

    printf("%d %d\n",num1,num2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "That is because arguments are passed by value", thank you

Comment: Does you swap have problems when the integers in question are reaching there limits? Also why not use an integer on the stack as a temporary. Should be quicker as it may just be a register

Comment: @EdHeal because 'XOR swap' looks and sounds cool.  Intuitively difficult to comprehend and inflexible, but cool.

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work because when you call the procedure, it is made a copy of the arguments to the new scope.

The right way is with the address of the variables.

Change to:

```
swap(&num1,&num2);
```

and

```
void swap(int *A,int *B)
{
    *A = *A + *B;
    *B = *A - *B;
    *A = *A - *B;
}
```

Comment: Why all the kerfuffle and not use a local variable?

Comment: I have no idea. Irony: to save memory?

Comment: I am of the opinion that one should write code that is easy to read and understand. Requires less thinking and therefore not prone to errors. Helps people maintaining code along a bit